# No output after passing component as a dependency in the main app module

Tags: angularjs

I am learning  angularjs phonecat tutorial, its working fine till step 3 where i create phonelist component. But in step 4 when i declare a seperate module for the phonelist component(phone-list.module.js) and modify app.js and phone-list.component.js, I am not getting any output in the browser.The moment i pass phonelist in the dependency array when defining phoncatapp  module it doesnt work.

```
// APP.MODULE.JS
  angular.module('phonecatApp', [
'phoneList'
  ]);


// PHONE-LIST.COMPONENT.JS
angular.
  module('phonecatList').
  component('phoneList', {  
 templateUrl:'phone-list.template.html',
 controller: function PhoneListController() {
  this.phones = [
    {
      name: 'Nexus S',
      snippet: 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'
    }, {
      name: 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
      snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
    }, {
      name: 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
      snippet: 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
     }
    ];
    }
   });

  //PHONE-LIST.MODULE.JS 
  angular.module('phoneList',[]);


  <!Doctype html>
  <html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
  <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Google Phone Gallery</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
 <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 <script src="phone-list.module.js"></script>
 <script src="phone-list.component.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>

 <phone-list></phone-list>

  </body>
 </html>
```